# HotSpot stack guard pages. Red/Yellow zones and reasons behind them

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Java Threads stack organization is described by the following [diagram in comments](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp#l5861). So the 1 glibc guard page seems to be the default value which is set by `pthread_attr_init(pthread_attr*)`.

The reason I could imagine behind red/yellow zones is handling stack-overflow without receiving `SIGSEGV`. Also red-zone here definitely means something different from what is specified in [System V AMD64 ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) which is set to 128 byte below `rsp` and is meant to stay untouched by interrupt/signal handlers.

The HotSpot red zone is controlled by `-XX:StackRedPages` option and as far as I tried it could be `0` to `3` pages in size.

What I also found was that when primordial thread creates a thread which performs the initialization steps it [sets the `pthread` guard size to 0](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/unix/native/libjli/java_md_solinux.c#l745).

**Q:** What are red/yellow zones are for and why the thread performing the initialization is created without `pthread` guard pages?

Comment: See [Stack Overflow handling in HotSpot JVM](https://pangin.pro/posts/stack-overflow-handling)

Comment: @apangin. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux one (probably of some others) usage for red and yellow_reserved zones is to make JVM HotSpot handles stack overflow. `pthreads_attr_setguardsize` man page has a note about setting guard size to 0:

> it is the application's responsibility to handle stack overflow
>   (perhaps by using `mprotect(2)` to manually define a guard area at the
>   end of the stack that it has allocated).

and

> Setting a guard size of 0 may be useful to save memory in  an 
>   application  that  creates  many threads and knows that stack overflow
>   can never occur.

So since no threads (even a primordial one) use `MAP_GROWSDOWN` mapping for their stack setting the guard size to 0 at this [point](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/unix/native/libjli/java_md_solinux.c#l745) can probably be treated as an optimization. The "stackoverflow never occur" is guaranteed by the `reserved`/`yellow`/`red` pages that JVM manually maps in the function [`void JavaThread::create_stack_guard_pages()`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/runtime/thread.cpp#l2537).

As can be seen, some part at the bottom of thread's stack even with no `pthread`'s guard pages is treated as [HotSpot Guard Pages](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp#l5870) that is [guarded](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/runtime/thread.cpp#l2559) with `mprotect` right as the manual page told us to do.

The actual handling of stack overflow is done via [signal handler](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/os_linux_x86.cpp#l273) that is installed on JVM startup. The part related to stack overflow is this (a bit long):

```
// Handle ALL stack overflow variations here
if (sig == SIGSEGV) {
  address addr = (address) info->si_addr;
  // check if fault address is within thread stack
  if (thread->on_local_stack(addr)) {
    // stack overflow
    if (thread->in_stack_yellow_reserved_zone(addr)) {
      if (thread->thread_state() == _thread_in_Java) {
        if (thread->in_stack_reserved_zone(addr)) {
          frame fr;
          if (os::Linux::get_frame_at_stack_banging_point(thread, uc, &fr)) {
            assert(fr.is_java_frame(), "Must be a Java frame");
            frame activation =
              SharedRuntime::look_for_reserved_stack_annotated_method(thread, fr);
            if (activation.sp() != NULL) {
              thread->disable_stack_reserved_zone();
              if (activation.is_interpreted_frame()) {
                thread->set_reserved_stack_activation((address)(
                  activation.fp() + frame::interpreter_frame_initial_sp_offset));
              } else {
                thread->set_reserved_stack_activation((address)activation.unextended_sp());
              }
              return 1;
            }
          }
        }
        // Throw a stack overflow exception.  Guard pages will be reenabled
        // while unwinding the stack.
        thread->disable_stack_yellow_reserved_zone();
        stub = SharedRuntime::continuation_for_implicit_exception(thread, pc, SharedRuntime::STACK_OVERFLOW);
      } else {
        // Thread was in the vm or native code.  Return and try to finish.
        thread->disable_stack_yellow_reserved_zone();
        return 1;
      }
    } else if (thread->in_stack_red_zone(addr)) {
      // Fatal red zone violation.  Disable the guard pages and fall through
      // to handle_unexpected_exception way down below.
      thread->disable_stack_red_zone();
      tty->print_raw_cr("An irrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.");
      // This is a likely cause, but hard to verify. Let's just print
      // it as a hint.
      tty->print_raw_cr("Please check if any of your loaded .so files has "
                        "enabled executable stack (see man page execstack(8))");
    } else {
       //...
```

As can be noticed from the code. If the `SIGSEGV` is raised when on the reserved or yellow zone the guard pages are unguarded, the `StackOverflowError` error is dispatched into Java and the guard is re-enabled on stack unwinding.

By contrast, if the `SIGSEGV` is raised when in red zone it is treated as "irrecoverable stack overflow error".

For example:

```
public class Main {
    static void foo() throws Exception {
        foo();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        foo();
    }
}
```

as can be noticed with `gdb` this `StackOverflowError` occurred in reserved/yellow zone, not in the red (so this is probably the reason it can be handled by the `try`-`catch` handler).

As a conclusion the HotSpot guard red zone has completely different meaning from [AMD64 System V ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) red zone definition (simply the area that a caller can put local vars so that they are not touched by signal/interrupt handler or probably by debuggers since `gdb` might put its own data on the stack outside of the red zone).